# How to toggle button in button-group on page load in bootstrap3 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a button group like below

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="environment" id="staging" value="staging" />Staging
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="environment" id="production" value="production" />Production
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to toggle to production on page load. I'm doing below to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#production").button('toggle');
}
```

But nothing is happening. How should I do this ? Also, how do I know which button is active ?

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.2 with Jquery 1.11.1

Comment: On a sider note, using radio as button in button groups is horribly confusing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button is represented by `label`. So all you need to do is to call `button` method on the parent label element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#production").parent().button('toggle');
});
```

Or much better, if you want to make production selected by default you should add class `active` in HTML in the first place:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="environment" id="staging" value="staging" />Staging
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="environment" id="production" value="production" />Production
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: how will I know which button is active ?

Comment: I did not want to add active to production by default because, I want to hit a change event on button - on page load. The change event will update some text boxes. I did not want to repeat code for filling those text boxes on page load and on change.

Comment: *"how will I know which button is active"*. Check which one of them has class active.

Comment: Ohk so I would I expect it to be $("btn btn-default active").child().val(); May be I should add a 'id' to the label.