# Read radio button value on button-grp toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a follow up question for [How to toggle button in button-group on page load in bootstrap3 with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314815/how-to-toggle-button-in-button-group-on-page-load-in-bootstrap3-with-jquery)

I'm trying to read a value of radio in a button group. I'm able to read the value on click of a button, but not on change trigger.

```
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="environment" id="staging" value="staging" />Staging
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="environment" id="production" value="production" />Production
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="get-active">Get active</button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#production").parent().button('toggle');
        });
        $('.get-active').click(function() {
            var active = $('.btn-group').find('.active input').val();
            alert( active );
        });
        $("#staging").parent().on('change', function(){
                    var active = $('.btn-group').find('.active input').val();
            alert( active );
              });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/QwGYXNqNczbgTfMhqey5?p=preview

On click toggle to staging from production, it shows an alert as undefined, which clicking button shows staging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is I think that `.active input` class has not been added when `change` is fired. it gets added later on. so it does't find the value. I dont if this solution works for you but you could do something like this.
Define a class for the button. For example:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="environment" id="staging" class="radioClass" value="staging" />Staging
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="environment" id="production" class="radioClass" value="production" />Production
        </label>
```

Then in jquery call change on that class

```
$('.radioClass').on('change', function(){
                    var active = $(this).val();
            alert( active );
              });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9mnbGFhukwWVZSmwq2qZ?p=preview

Comment: thanks. This solution worked. But keeping this open to see if any one else knows the root cause or if there is a better solution.